# How to retrieve row in DB Table just added now in Java

Tags: java, sql, mysql

Table

id     int(11)             No          auto_increment        Change      Drop        Primary         Index       Unique     Fulltext

email   varchar(45)     latin1_swedish_ci       No              Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

billpayment     tinyint(1)          No              Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

dispatch    tinyint(1)          No              Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

address     varchar(75)     latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL        Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

phone   int(11)             Yes     NULL        Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

created_at      datetime            No              Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

totalbillamount     float           Yes     NULL        Change  Drop    Primary     Index   Unique  Fulltext

Java Code:

```
        sql = "insert into session_shopping (email,billpayment,dispatch,address,phone,created_at,totalbillamount) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, email);
        ps.setBoolean(2, false);
        ps.setBoolean(3, false);
        ps.setString(4, "");
        ps.setInt(5, 0);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        long t = date.getTime();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(t);
        ps.setDate(6, sqlDate);
        ps.setFloat(7, 00.0f);
        int newId = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("newId" + newId);
        if (newId == 1) {
            sql = "select * from session_shopping where id = ?";
            ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, newId);
            ResultSet reS = ps.executeQuery();
            Session s = new Session();
            s.setId(reS.getInt("id"));
            s.setEmail(reS.getString("email"));
            System.out.println("retreived");
            return s;
        } else {
            System.out.println("unable to save");
        }
```

This code fails because int newId is boolean

What i want to do is. I want to retrieve the row which i added just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

executeUpdate will return the number of rows affected, not the current row .

Try this

```
ResultSet rs = aStatement.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
while(rs.next()) 
{
  key =  rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `executeUpdate` has nothing to do with your ID.

Before we go to getting your ID, you can start off by setting email in the Session from your email variable rather than pulling it back out of the database.

As things stand, the only way I can think of to get the newly inserted ID is by changing your SQL thus:

```
sql = "select max(id) from session_shopping";
```

This will give you problems if you get another insert before you pick out the maximum ID though. To prevent that, put the select in the same transaction as your insert.