# How to get an automatically incremented column value when inserting a row into a table in mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql, select, insert

How can I insert into table1 like: `INSERT INTO table1 (description) VALUES ('Some test description here');` and have it return the automatically incremented ID so that I can then insert a row into table2? The description is not guaranteed to be unique. I am using a Java `PreparedStatement` to insert the value currently with `execute()`

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    table1ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY (table1ID)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    table1ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    personID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table2 PRIMARY KEY (table1ID, personID)
);

ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table1_table2
FOREIGN KEY (table1ID) REFERENCES table1 (table1ID);

ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table2_person
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES person (personID);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retreive row in DB Table just added now in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018379/how-to-retreive-row-in-db-table-just-added-now-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run this query right after the insert completes succesfully: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
                    "Insert into table1 (name) values ('test desc')",
                    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            st.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                int data = rs.getRow(); 
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
```

Observe values of data & id.

You don't need to fire insert & select queries separately.